# If P != NP, can every NP-complete language be partitioned into two NP-complete subsets?

Tags: complexity-theory

Assuming $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, then all NP-complete languages are countably infinite. I know not all subsets are NP-complete, but I am wondering if there's a simple proof that every NP-complete language can be partitioned into two subsets $X,Y$ such that both $X$ and $Y$ are NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think a partition always exists. My idea is to first prove it for $\text{Clique}$ and then use the fact that $\text{Clique}$can be reduced to every other $\textsf{NP}$-complete problem.

In a first step, we prove that it is possible for the language $\text{Clique}$ by considering the length of inputs.
We will measure the length of an input $x$ for $\text{Clique}$ in the number of nodes to avoid a technical problem.
Let $\text{Clique}_{even}=\{x\in\text{Clique}\mid |x| \text{ is even}\}$ and $\text{Clique}_{odd}=\{x\in\text{Clique}\mid |x| \text{ is odd}\}$.
Then $\text{Clique}=\text{Clique}_{odd}\cup \text{Clique}_{even}$ is a partition with the desired property: Both languages are in $\textsf{NP}$ and we can reduce $\text{SAT}$ to both languages by using the reduction from $\text{SAT}$ to $\text{Clique}$ where we add an additional isolated node if the size of the constructed graph doesn't fit the restriction.

Now, let $L$ be an arbitrary $\textsf{NP}$-complete language. So, there is a polynomial-time reduction $f$ from $\text{Clique}$ to $L$. In particular, there is a polynom $p$ that bounds the size of the constructed object, so $|f(x)|\leq p(|x|)$.
Without loss of generality we can assume $|x|<|f(x)|$, so $|x|<|f(x)|<p(|x|)$.

We use this polynom $p$ to define two sets $N_1,N_2$ of the natural numbers. Set $1,2,\dots,p(1)\in N_1$, $p(1)+1,\dots,p(p(1)+1)\in N_2$, $p(p(1)+1)+1,\dots,p(p(p(1)+1)+1)\in N_1$ and so on.
So, $N_1$ and $N_2$ consist of infinitely many finite sequences of consecutive numbers.
Next, let $L_1=\{x\in L\mid |x|\in N_1\}$ and $L_2=\{x\in L\mid |x|\in N_2\}$. Both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are in $\textsf{NP}$, we can just use the algorithm for $L$ and then check the length afterwards.

Finally, we show that $\text{Clique}$ can be reduced to $L_1$, the reduction to $L_2$ is analogous. Let $x$ be some input for $\text{Clique}$. If $|x|$ coincides with the end of a sequence in $N_2$ (for example $p(p(1)+1)$) then we can apply $f$ and $|f(x)|\in N_1$, so the reduction works correctly. Otherwise, we can add isolated nodes to the graph represented by $x$ until $|x|$ coincides with an end of a sequence in $N_2$. We have to add at most polynomially many nodes because the length of the sequences is bounded by $p$. Thus, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are NP-complete.

The technical assumption can probably be avoided by choosing a diferent langauge than $\text{Clique}$. Also notice that the statement allows us to partition any $\textsf{NP}$-complete language into arbitrarily (finitely) many languages which are $\textsf{NP}$-complete. So, the size-blowup in the reduction $f$ can probably not be avoided.

Comment: Can you prove that (a) both $\mathrm{Clique}_{\mathit{even}}$ and $\mathrm{Clique}_{\mathit{odd}}$ are infinite sets and (b) both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are infinite sets? I believe that part (a) is rather dependent on the choice of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. If you can enumerate all the possible instances of your problem N, then you divide them into "even" and "odd" instances. You could now have one problem saying NOdd asking "Is I is an odd instance of N, and does N answer YES" and a problem NEven asking "Is I an even instance of N, and does N answer YES".

Sounds easy. But I'm sure someone can construct a problem where one of NOdd and NEven is trivial. Actually, NOdd has exactly the same instances as N. So if you apply the "NEven" construction to Odd instead of N, then the resulting language always returns NO and is therefore trivial.

If N is very compressed (with no redundancy at all), so that some instance of some problem in NP can only be solved by constructing exactly ONE instance in N, then that one instance cannot be both in NEven and in NOdd, and one of the two languages is not NP-complete.

So we have a different question now: Is there an NP-complete problem, and a problem in NP with an instance where not AT LEAST  instance of the the NP-complete problem, but EXACTLY one instance can be used to solve the problem in the NP language?

Comment: As you said, this won't work for $L$ having only odd-length words. Tiny fix: enumerate $L$ without repetitions and partition according to the parity of sequence numbers.